# Unable to set DropWizard Logging Time Zone same as Host

Tags: dropwizard

I have the following logging configuration on a DropWizard project:

```
logging:
  level: INFO
  appenders:
    - type: console
      threshold: INFO
      target: stdout
```

Which seems to use by default the UTC time zone looking at the times in the generated logs. The host where this application is running is in WET and if I change the log config to:

```
logging:
  level: INFO
  appenders:
    - type: console
      threshold: INFO
      target: stdout
      timeZone: WET
```

Then the log messages have the same time as the host.

Is there a mechanism so that DW could set the time zone to be the same as the host automatically or do we need to specify the exact time zone in which the log messages are to be generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you can [set the appender's timezone to the timezone of the host](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/1980) with:

```
timeZone: system
```